How to configure clangd in VSCode to also show the declaration header file for hovered symbols
When I hover a symbol clangd in VSCode will tell me what namespace it is in and nicely substitute template arguments (if any). But what would be more helpful would be the header file where the symbol comes from. This is what I see now:

For std I generally either remember the headers or can look them up in cppreference, but for internal ones I have to Ctrl+Click the symbol and then pick the file which is a header and is not a forward declaration.
Is there a way to configure what this preview contains, or even better a script I can place somewhere to transform it to my needs?

Clangd has very few configuration options, so it's unlikely.

Submit a feature request https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-cpptools or start hacking and implement your own hover which would be a combination of textDocument/definition + textDocument/hover.

Clangd shows this information by default these days, as illustrated in the screenshot below.
Note the provided by <utility> (second line from the top).
This feature first appeared in clangd 17.

And here is an example of it working for a custom type (not from the standard library):


I can see if I even can update clangd (I have v15). But the main question is, will this work for my own symbols or is it only for std lib?

@TomášZato It works with your own symbols too. I edited the answer to add an example showing that.

Thanks a lot. I will investigate how to update clangd and accept if it works. Updating sounds like a reasonable solution, although I do wish I did get an answer on customizing the output in VSCode.

@TomášZato I don't believe there's any way to customize the hover contents in VSCode, short of writing your own plugin to talk to the clangd server in place of vscode-clangd (and even then, the customization ability would be limited to parsing the markdown the server returns and omitting sections of it, or rearranging it, or reformatting it).
